# Segmentation fault with vectors and iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I got a segmentation fault when trying to use one cpp file and tried to locate the error using Valgrind, but I'm confused.

Since the code is very large, I will only post a short portion of it below:

Comment: As a side note: Are you sure that your lab is fine with posting code exactly? Also, I'd post only code that's relevant to the error messages which you post. You are posting no errors related to any code. Ah. Jeremy's answer was faster :)

Comment: All those "???" can only mean you are not compiling it in debug mode.

Comment: You're doing things like this:  `int nV = geo.getNumVerts(); for(int i=0; i<nV; i++) {canDecimate[i] = 0;` but I don't know if `canDecimate` has at least `nV` items.  If anything can cause issues, it is using a single upper bound value for two differing containers/arrays.

Comment: @csx - Your code in general just assumes the values are "in range".  In other words, your code does no error checking whatsoever.  To fix it, you put the requisite checks in your code to ensure you're accessing items that are in bounds.  You added this to your post `int tri = *iter; if(triann[tri].a != v)` again, no check if `*iter` is in range (assuming that `triann` is an array, vector, or similar type).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running valgrind on the compiler.  Unless you are trying to debug the compiler, you should be running valgrind on your application instead:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./MyApp
```

(replace `./MyApp` with the appropriate executable name and arguments, of course)

(Explanation:  valgrind is a run-time analysis tool; it takes your application as input.  It is not a compiler tool like some of the other debugging tools that are out there)

Comment: @csx give the name of your executable